# Avoid additional overloading functions with union types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types

I'm developing several wrappers of different mappers based on the number of provided arguments and I'd like to manage both the traditional TS functions and the new wrappers using just one type:

```
/**
 * Union type of {@link FFunction2} and {@link Function2}
 */
type TFunction2<T1, T2, R> = FFunction2<T1, T2, R> | Function2<T1, T2, R>;


/**
 * Represents the lambda approach of a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result.
 *
 * @typeParam <T1>
 *   Type of the first input to the {@link FFunction2}
 * @typeParam <T2>
 *   Type of the second input to the {@link FFunction2}
 * @typeParam <R>
 *   Type of the result of the {@link FFunction2}
 */
 type FFunction2<T1, T2, R> = (t1: T1, t2: T2) => R;


 /**
  * Verifies if the given `input` is potentially an instance of {@link FFunction2}.
  * <p>
  *    It is important to know `input` could be 'something' different from {@link FFunction2}. To improve
  * the performance:
  * <p>
  *   1. Its type has been compared to a function.
  *   2. Check its number of parameters, however the default ones are not considered by the `length` function.
  *
  * @param input
  *    Object to verify
  *
  * @return `true` if `input` is potentially an instance of {@link FFunction2},
  *         `false` otherwise
  */
 function isFFunction2<T1, T2, R>(input?: any): input is FFunction2<T1, T2, R> {
   return null !== input &&
     undefined !== input && 
     'function' === typeof input &&
     2 === input.length;
 }
```

And this is the **wrapper**:

```
 /**
  * Represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result, used as wrapper of {@link FFunction2}.
  * <p>
  * This is a functional interface whose functional method is {@link Function2#apply}.
  *
  * @typeParam<T1>
  *   Type of the first input to the {@link Function2}
  * @typeParam<T2>
  *   Type of the second input to the {@link Function2}
  * @typeParam <R>
  *   Type of the result of the {@link Function2}
  */
  class Function2<T1, T2, R> {

    protected constructor(protected readonly mapper: FFunction2<T1, T2, R>) {}


    /**
     * Verifies if the given `input` is an instance of {@link Function2}.
     *
     * @param input
     *    Object to verify
     *
     * @return `true` if `input` is an instance of {@link Function2},
     *         `false` otherwise
     */
     static isFunction = <T1, T2, R>(input?: any): input is Function2<T1, T2, R> =>
       null !== input &&
       undefined !== input &&
       undefined !== (input as Function2<T1, T2, R>).apply &&
       undefined !== (input as Function2<T1, T2, R>).getMapper &&
       isFFunction2((input as Function2<T1, T2, R>).getMapper());


     static of<T1, T2, R>(func: FFunction2<T1, T2, R>): Function2<T1, T2, R>;
     static of<T1, T2, R>(func: TFunction2<T1, T2, R>): Function2<T1, T2, R>;

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Function2} describing the given {@link FFunction2}.
     *
     * @param func
     *    {@link FFunction2} used to evaluates the given instances of T and return an R one
     *
     * @return an {@link Function2} as wrapper of `mapper`
     *
     * @throws {@link TypeError} if `func` is `null` or `undefined`
     */
     static of<T1, T2, R>(func: TFunction2<T1, T2, R>): Function2<T1, T2, R> {
       if (null === func || undefined === func) {
         throw new TypeError('func is null or undefined');
       }
       return Function2.isFunction<T1, T2, R>(func)
         ? func
         : new Function2(func);
     }


    /**
     * Returns internal `mapper`.
     *
     * @return {@link FFunction2}
     */
     getMapper = (): FFunction2<T1, T2, R> =>
       this.mapper;


    /**
     * Applies this {@link Function2} to the given argument.
     *
     * @param t1
     *    The first input argument
     * @param t2
     *    The second input argument
     *
     * @return new instance of R
     */
     apply = (t1: T1,
              t2: T2): R =>
       this.mapper(t1, t2);

  }
```

The current code works well, same that the next examples:

```
const fLambda = 
  (s: string, n: number) => s.length + n;

const fFFunction: FFunction2<string, number, number> =
  (s: string, n: number) => s.length + n;

const fFunction: Function2<string, number, number> =
  Function2.of(
    (s: string, n: number) => s.length + n
  );

const fLambdaToFunction = Function2.of(fLambda);
const fFFunctionToFunction = Function2.of(fFFunction);
const fFunctionToFunction = Function2.of(fFunction);
```

However, it's mandatory to include three `of` definitions because when I removed the first 2 ones, due to **TFunction2** should contains both, I receive the error message:

```
Type 'Function2<string, number, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Function2<string, number, number>'.
```

`TFunction2` is just one example, I have developed several other wrappers using the same approach. So every time I develop a new method using one of them, I have to include 3 different definitions:

```
methodX<T1, T2, R>(func: FFunction2<T1, T2, R>);

methodX<T1, T2, R>(func: TFunction2<T1, T2, R>);

methodX<T1, T2, R>(func: TFunction2<T1, T2, R>) {
   // Body of the method
}
```

Increasing the required number of definitions if the method uses different ones: `TFunction2`, `TFunction3`, etc

So, taking into account `TFunction2` is a union type containing "all the options":

1. How could I keep only the last `of` method? (assuming the same approach could be applied to the other methods: `methodX`)
2. I know can use the following:

   ```
   const fFunction: Function2<string, number, number> =
     Function2.of<string, number, number>(
       (s: string, n: number) => s.length + n
     );
   ```

but I would like to avoid adding this kind of extra code.

Comment: This is mostly an issue with inference, and overloading is one way to deal with that issue.  If you *require* not using overloads then you can do it some other way, like changing the generic type and using conditional type inference on it, possibly [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mxy6ZW), but that looks worse to me than overloads. What are the constraints here? What actual problem do you have with overloads (aside from stylistic concerns which are presumably secondary to functionality)?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your response. I'm working in a project to provide different generic functionality to manage Arrays, Maps, etc. like the following: https://github.com/doctore/AngularUtil/blob/main/src/app/core/util/map.util.ts  above wrapper is one of the classes I use as base of provided functionality and, as you can see, overloading was the best solution I found to deal with the problem. I wanted to know a better approach to avoid it

Comment: But why do you want to avoid it? Is there some functionality problem that happens with overloads? Or is it just some stylistic issue? If it's a stylistic issue then can you explicitly describe it in the question? The notion of "a better approach" depends on some subjective value system that different people don't necessarily share, so right now this might be just an opinion-based question. If you could articulate explicitly the criteria for determining a "better" approach, then maybe there could be some objective answer. Otherwise this doesn't seem like a good fit for SO.

Comment: Considering `TFunction2` contains both the traditional TS functions and the new wrapper, I would like to define only one function using it. `TFunction2` is just one use case, I have developed several and every time I create a new method using them, I have to include 3 different definitions.

Comment: And is [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mxy6ZW) worse?  It's worse, right?  I don't think there's anything better than overloads.

Comment: **And is this version worse?** => yes, because I'll need to do it with every new developed function using a parameter of those types: `TFunction2`, `TFunction3`, etc  (some methods even using more than one of different wrappers) **I don't think there's anything better than overloads** => ok, thanks for your feedback and response. This is probably the answer to my question.

Comment: I see the request to close the question, **this isn't an opinion based one** I have developed several wrappers using this approach and dozen of functions using them (some even with more than one type). I wanted to know why when I define a union type with "all the options" => I have to include 3 function's definitions by every different wrapper. So if I developed 100 functions using 2 different of those types in every case => potentially I have to include 600 definitions.

Comment: If the answer is **because there is no a better choice**, ok, I can deal with that. However, in my professional opinion this is a lack in the provided functionality in TS, and yes, **this is an opinion based one**.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to reflect the clarifications from the comments? Specifically why you want to remove the overloads and what criteria you are using to determine what's better/worse than the overloads? Right now, as asked, the question says something like "how can I do this without overloads" and my awful conditional type suggestion meets that criterion but isn't actually what you're looking for. Once the question is edited to clearly lay out what is and is not acceptable, then maybe we can write "there's no better choice according to your criteria" as an answer.

Comment: Done, added more information to the question based on previous comments.